# Kafka Streams Processor with WindowStore Unit Test ClassCastException

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, classcastexception

I was attempting to write a unit test for a class implementing the `Processor` interface that contained a `WindowStore`, but running the test fails with a `ClassCastException` coming out of `InMemoryWindowStore.init` attempting to cast `MockProcessorContext` to `InternalProcessorContext`.

Googling for this problem isn't turning up anything useful, or indicating that it's a known problem. I'm attempting to follow the guidance in [the documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/22/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html), but perhaps I'm still missing something.

I've created a repository with a minimal example to reproduce the problem on [Github](https://github.com/fetherolfjd/kafka-streams-proc-unit-test) if someone would care to reference it directly.

But otherwise, the processor class is:

```
package com.cantgetthistowork;

import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Processor;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorContext;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.WindowStore;

public class InMemWindowProcessor implements Processor<String, String> {

  private ProcessorContext context;
  private WindowStore<String, String> windowStore;

  @Override
  public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    this.context = context;

    windowStore = (WindowStore<String, String>) context.getStateStore("my-win-store");
  }

  @Override
  public void process(String key, String value) {
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
  }

}
```

And the test class is:

```
package com.cantgetthistowork;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.MockProcessorContext;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.Stores;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.WindowStore;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class InMemWindowProcessorTest {

  InMemWindowProcessor processor = null;
  MockProcessorContext context = null;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    processor = new InMemWindowProcessor();
    context = new MockProcessorContext();

    WindowStore<String, String> store =
      Stores.windowStoreBuilder(
        Stores.inMemoryWindowStore(
          "my-win-store",
          Duration.ofMinutes(10),
          Duration.ofSeconds(10),
          false
        ),
        Serdes.String(),
        Serdes.String()
      )
      .withLoggingDisabled()
      .build();
    store.init(context, store);
    context.register(store, null);
    processor.init(context);
  }

  @Test
  public void testThings() {
    Instant baseTime = Instant.now();
    context.setTimestamp(baseTime.toEpochMilli());
    context.setTopic("topic-name");
    processor.process("key1", "value1");
  }

}
```

I'm using maven as my build tool `mvn --version` outputting:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T13:39:06-06:00)
Maven home: ~/opt/apache-maven-3.5.0
Java version: 1.8.0_212, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-52-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

And finally, `mvn test` outputs:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.cantgetthistowork.InMemWindowProcessorTest
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.076 sec <<< FAILURE!
testThings(com.cantgetthistowork.InMemWindowProcessorTest)  Time elapsed: 0.05 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.MockProcessorContext cannot be cast to org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalProcessorContext
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.InMemoryWindowStore.init(InMemoryWindowStore.java:91)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.init(MeteredWindowStore.java:90)
    at com.cantgetthistowork.InMemWindowProcessorTest.setup(InMemWindowProcessorTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  testThings(com.cantgetthistowork.InMemWindowProcessorTest): org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.MockProcessorContext cannot be cast to org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalProcessorContext

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

So yeah, maybe I'm just missing some configuration, or doing something out of order, or otherwise foolish. In the mean time I was going to write tests that make use of `TopologyTestDriver`, and hopefully that works.

I look forward to any responses/ideas that folks may have.

Comment: That is a bug... Can you please create a JIRA for it? In-memory window stores where added recently and it seems we did not test if they work with the `MockProcessorContext` :( Using TopologyTestDriver should hopefully work -- IIRC, we have corresponding tests.

Comment: Thanks. JIRA ticket has been created. Using `TopologyTestDriver` does indeed work.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8630